# How does P6SPY work?

Tags: p6spy

Pretty much everything in the question. I just discovered p6spy in association with hibernate which is really cool to see the actual sql queries, though I'm quite baffled on how it works.
So how does it work?

Answer (score 3):

the basic idea on p6spy goes like this:

1. depending if you go for `Datasource` or for `JDBC driver` in your code,
   what you do is instead of referring the real ones, you specify p6spy
   specific ones: `com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver` or `com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6DataSource` respectively (for full documentation, see: [p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configandusage.html](http://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configandusage.html)).
2. afterwards you configure the real ones in your `spy.properties` file (using `realdriver` or `realdatasource` properties respectively)
3. depending on the configuration you can achieve the logging of sql statements (using `com.p6spy.engine.logging.P6LogFactory`)
4. so to answer your question, the idea is that all the jdbc calls (statements execution, transaction related stuff) will be wrapped (proxied) by p6spy and depending on your configuration, these can be logged via the file logger (using `appender=com.p6spy.engine.logging.appender.FileLogger`), stdout logger (using `appender=com.p6spy.engine.logging.appender.StdoutLogger`) or log4j logger (using: `appender=com.p6spy.engine.logging.appender.Log4jLogger`)

If interested in more details, feel free to ask, or check the project itself on: https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy